# Can't change Backlight brightness in Asus ul20A

Tags: bios, backlight

I have Asus ul20A and what I think is the newest netbook version of Ubuntu, and I can't seem to find a way to change my screen's brightness. It's a shame, because it takes hours off my battery life.

Googling offered an answer: Upgrade my BIOS to 210. The thing is, my computer doesn't have a CD slot. So How can I upgrade my BIOS, or is there another way to change my screen brightness?

I have already tried tweaking lines in grub and xbacklight, so they do nothing.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't even close to a complete answer, but this page on the kernel's team page might shed some light on figuring out the backlight problem:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight